# opencart moving to domain

Tags: php, web, opencart

i moved my website from a subdomain which was made in opencart to a domain by moving the files and exporting and importing the database, and changing the config.php file but i got this errors:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/inti/public_html/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/smartmobile/public_html/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/inti/public_html/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/smartmobile/public_html/index.php on line 17
```

Comment: Check the permission of that files. File permission should be atleast 644

Answer (score 0):

This is most of times folder permission issue or the path set in config files is not valid.

You can get the path by

```
echo getcwd();
```

And use this path in config files.

Permissions can be checked and changed via many methods depending upon your access to server.